# Comparing html text inputs and redirecting to another page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, text, input

I am brand new to Javascript and am just using it to make a simple website for fun. I have tried searching the web but am still stuck, so if you could help me or redirect me towards other help, that would be great.
I am trying to use Javascript to send a user to another html page in my site if their input matches my criteria. So I wanted to use an if/else statement to do this: if the text input equals `ODQHVHMJKD`, it would send them to `page3.html`. However when I try this on the browser, nothing happens--it just takes me to an identical page with `?codebox1=f&button1=Submit` at the end of the address.
Here is my script section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testResults (form) {
    if (form.codebox1.value == ODQHVHMJKD) {
    window.location.pathname = 'page3.html';
    }
    else {
        window.alert("Try again!");
    }  
};
</script>
```

Here are my form elements:

```
<form name="form1" method="GET">
<input name="codebox1" type="text" />
<input name="button1" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="testResults(this.form)"/>
</form>
```

Can you help me so that I can get this to work? It's more than likely I've done everything completely wrong--any help is appreciated!

Comment: So I added `return false` and quotes. The alert box works but when I type the correct answer it still doesn't take me to the new page. Any suggestions? I've made sure I'm using the right file name.

Comment: I got it all to work! I was using `window.open` incorrectly. I changed it to `window.open("page3.html");` and now everything seems to be just fine!

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default action of the form. In the submit event, call `e.preventDefault();` or `return false` In addition, you need quotation marks around `ODQHVHMJKD`

Js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/Ht45t/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
function testResults (form) {
    if (form.codebox1.value == "ODQHVHMJKD") {
        window.location = 'page3.html';
    }
    else {
        window.alert("Try again!");
    }  
    return false;
};
```

Comment: This works in that the alert box now shows up when I type in the wrong answer, but I'm still having trouble linking to the new page. I've triple checked that I'm using the right name, so I don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.

```
    <form name="form" onsubmit="Results()">
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="val">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Results() {
          var val = document.getElementById('val').value;
          if (val == "ODQHVHMJKD") {
              window.location = 'page3.html';
           } else {
              window.alert("Try again!");
           }  
        };
    </script>
```